# Moving similar elements from one list to another

Tags: python, list, element

In short, I am trying to detect if there are 4 of a kind of one element in a list and then move all 4 of those elements to another list. So far I have:

```
human_hand = [4,5,6,4,5,3,4,5,4]
discard = [] 


for i in set(human_hand):
    if human_hand.count(i) == 4:
        discard.append(i)

print discard
```

However, my issue is that once the first one gets appended the boolean is not triggered any longer. New to python and stumped. I also realize I do not have an else statement right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are iterating over a `set`.

Set objects does not allow multiple items, so if you have your list `[4,5,6,4,5,3,4,5,4]` , the resulting set will be `[3,4,5,6]`.
You are then iterating over `[3,4,5,6]`, so that's why it will only get into the `if` statement once: only when `i == 4`.

I don't know what you intend to do there, but if you wish to append all four elements from `human_hand` into `discard`, an easier way would be not to iterate over the set:

```
for i in human_hand:
    if human_hand.count(i) == 4:
        discard.append(i)
```

#### Edit

If you want to append 4 times do `discard` list, but only notice once the user if there are not 4 of the number, you can use:

```
for i in set(human_hand):
    if human_hand.count(i) == 4:
        discard.extend([i]*4)
    else:
        print "There aren't 4 of a kind for the number ", i
```

That will append to discard list the list `[4,4,4,4]` but only notice once if there are no 4 items of other numbers.

Comment: Ok cool. That brings me closer.  However, if I add an else statement along the lines of "You do not have 4 of a kind" it will trigger that for every value that I do not have 4 of a kind for. So, now i have all my 4's in "discard" but it is also printing "Do not have 4 of a kind" 5 times. What should I put in my else statement? What I want is IF there is 4 of a kind then I want those values appended, and if there is not then I want the else statement triggered

Comment: Should I not do a for-loop then and just stick to an if-statement?

Comment: The thing is that I do not want it to say if I have 4 of a kind for each number. I just want it to look at my list. See if I have 4 of a kind of any of the distinct elements in it. If there are then I want to append those 4 of a kind to discard. If there isnt then I want it to continue reading the code below. It might help to know that I am practicing programming by coding the Go-Fish card game.

Comment: Then just remove the `else` part, and the code will do exactly what you want! :)

Comment: Awesome. Thank you. I was under the impression that every if-statement must have an else statement.

Answer (score 0):

When calling `for i in set(human_hand)`you are iterating over a set, so each number is only represented once. If you want to append each time 4 appears in the original, simply iterate over `for i in human_hand`